# How to check lowest numeric column (PL SQL)

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Return zip code with the largest total car purchases.  Since there can be a tie with two or more zip codes, ensure that the lowest numeric zip code is returned

**Table Schema:**
[image]

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Zip_code_sales_winner
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  total NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT max(y.[total purchases]) IN total
  FROM   (
                    SELECT     count(c.zip) AS 'Total Purchases'
                    FROM       customers c
                    inner join sales s
                    ON         c.cust_id=s.cust_id
                    inner join vehicles v
                    ON         s.vin=v.vin
                    GROUP BY   c.zip,
                               v.make) y;

  RETURN total;
END
```

The problem is max can return multiple values and I want to return only 1 value with lowest numeric zip code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (your subquery) WHERE ROWNUM=1

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is lexicographically sorting in two dimensions, first by zip-based counts in decreasing order and then by increasing zip code

```
SELECT z.tp
     , z.zip 
  INTO total
     , minzip
  FROM (
            SELECT y."Total purchases"    tp
                 , y.zip                  zip
              FROM (
                      SELECT     count(c.zip) AS "Total purchases"
                               , c.zip
                      FROM       customers c
                      inner join sales s
                      ON         c.cust_id=s.cust_id
                      inner join vehicles v
                      ON         s.vin=v.vin
                      GROUP BY   c.zip,
                                 v.make
                   ) y
          ORDER BY y."Total purchases" DESC
                 , y.zip               ASC
       ) z
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1              
     ;
```

Comment: @Zainulabdeen maybe because of the `[total purchases]` that you had in your original code. you're also grouping by `v.make`.

Comment: @Zainulabdeen I deleted a spurious closing parentheses and corrected the syntax of the non-standard identifier. A stripped-down version (with different tables, of course) works fine with me ( on 11g2 ).

Comment: Can you please post your working? with your tables of course

Answer (score 0):

Forget my former post about `Ceil` and `Floor`. They don't help in here.

You could try with another select which determins the min(%value%) from you query with the max Value.

Maybe something like that (untested):

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Zip_code_sales_winner
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  total NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT min(x.Value) IN total from (
  SELECT max(y.[total purchases]) Value
  FROM   (
                    SELECT     count(c.zip) AS 'Total Purchases'
                    FROM       customers c
                    inner join sales s
                    ON         c.cust_id=s.cust_id
                    inner join vehicles v
                    ON         s.vin=v.vin
                    GROUP BY   c.zip,
                               v.make) y) x;

  RETURN total;
END
```

Comment: I want zip code with minimum numeric values not "Total Purchases"

Answer (score 0):

You may also use analytic function to order the rows and get the first one.

This approach scale well if you want the extreme row per other dimension (e.g. per salesperson) - simple add `PARTITION BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

```
with your_query as (
   ....
),
ordered_query as (
  select "Total purchases", zip,
  row_number() over (order by "Total purchases" desc, zip) as rn
  from your_query
)
select "Total purchases", zip
from ordered_query
where rn = 1
```